# Can't Create Junction Table on BLUEHOST Mysql v5.5.42-37.1 but can on my Mac OSX MySQL v5.6.26

Tags: mysql

I recently purchased a BLUEHOST.COM shared PLUS account which comes with MySQL v5.5.42-37.1 for Linux and a bunch of other tools.

I am NOT able to creat a junction table on bluehost but can on my local Mac Pro computer.  The BLUEHOST server is running the MySQL version of:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42-37.1, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

My Mac Pro is running MySQL version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I successfully created a junction table linking my users table with my training_mod table.  I get the following error when I try this on the bluehost server.  NOTE:  I have tried this with MySQL Workbench and, more often as it is my prefered method, from a SSh command line via iTerm.

First, the output from 'SHOW TABLES;':

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_synnovat_pvfd |
+-------------------------+
| departments             |
| member_lastpos          |
| member_tracks           |
| members                 |
| training_mod            |
+-------------------------+
```

Here is the ERROR message I receive when I input the CREATE table SQL code below:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE member_training
    -> (
    -> uid VARCHAR(4),
    -> cid INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
    -> tid INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
    -> training_dt DATE,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (uid, cid),
    -> INDEX (uid, cid),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES training_mod (tid),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (uid, cid) REFERENCES members (uid, cid)
    -> ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )
    -> ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3165129
Current database: synnovat_pvfd

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'synnovat_pvfd.member_training' (errno: -1)

Now... doing this exact same SQL code on my local Mac's MySQL, it works.   See the same code executed below with NO ERRORS:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE member_training
    -> (
    -> uid VARCHAR(4),
    -> cid INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
    -> tid INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,
    -> training_dt DATE,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (uid, cid),
    -> INDEX (uid, cid),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES training_mod (tid),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (uid, cid) REFERENCES members (uid, cid)
    -> ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )
    -> ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Any idea other than perhaps MySQL 5.5.42-37.1 has a bug.  The BLUEHOST folks are clueless it seems and only said my SQL code looks right but they don't know what is up.

Comment: There's no such thing as "MySQL 5.5.42-37.1."  That looks more like a Percona Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION_COMMENT;` for detail). Percona is a compatible replacement for MySQL so that shouldn't be problematic, but it's important to know what you are dealing with.  In any event, a hosting provider that says "it should work, we can't explain why it doesn't" seems like a red flag.

Comment: Actually, this is a valid version number.  BlueHost.com runs it on their servers.  Here is the results of my 'mysql --version' I ranjust moments ago...

Comment: woops.  Here is the version

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42-37.1, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: As it turns out, there was some sort of issue with my actual database.  Not sure what it is/was and neither is the bluehost technical support tier 2 folks.  I was preparing a test for duplication testing by them and discovered in a second and third DB I had created that I could successfully use the code in my original post to create junction tables.  For some reason, they can't even delete the corrupt database.

Comment: Interesting... and not entirely unthinkable.  I've seen developers tweaking foreign key definitions get the server into similar states of internal inconsistency, but I've never replicated it. Incidentally, the version you showed is the *client* version (on your side or on the server, depending on where you ran `$ mysql`).  The server version is `SELECT @@VERSION;`.  I think we should probably close this one as a problem that can no longer be reproduced, since there's not really enough here to help future visitors.  This isn't a reflection on the quality of your question in this case.